# Font Size defined in Dimens file, displaying 3 times value in Java Class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fonts

I have defined these 3 values in `values/dimens.xml` folder.

```
<dimen name="newsFontLarge">32sp</dimen>
<dimen name="newsFontSmall">24sp</dimen>
<dimen name="newsFont">16sp</dimen>
```

I am getting these values in Java Code

```
    largeText= getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.newsFontLarge);
    smallText= getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.newsFontSmall);
    newsFont=  getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.newsFont);
```

The problem is that its not storing the actual value in Java class, but multiply value by 3 and store it in the variable; i.e

```
largeText= 96
smallText= 72
newsFont= 48
```

Kindly guide me how to store the actual values (that is defined in dimens) in java variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values you get from `getDimension()` are in **pixels**. The values in your resources are in **scaled pixels** (`sp`). Scaled pixels take into account screen density and the user's chosen font scale. In your case, I would guess that your device is an `xxhdpi` device (~480dpi) and is set for normal font scale, which would explain why 1 `sp` turns into 3 pixels.

Using `sp` for text sizes is an excellent choice.

You can read more about scaled pixels in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html#TaskUseDP).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Is there any formulae to convert PX to SP

Comment: @Kirmani88: Not really. Other than in the final stage of rendering to the screen, `px` is not a useful dimension unit of measure. You can convert from other units of measure *to* `px`, but not really the reverse.